# SQL Server : join tables including null values

Tags: sql-server, join

Here is my problem: I have two queries returning data like this:

```
Name    Quantity    Test
-------------------------
X        10          L
X        13          M
X        17          S
```

```
Name    Total
-------------
X       87
```

What I need is a query that returns a result like this:

```
Name   Quantity   Test   Total
--------------------------------
X       10          L    87
X       13          M    NULL
X       17          S    NULL
```

Query:

```
SELECT ag.vendnm
    ,bo3.u_nome
    ,bi.ETTDEB
    ,v.total2019
FROM bo(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN bi(NOLOCK) ON (bi.bostamp = bo.bostamp)
INNER JOIN bi2(NOLOCK) ON (bi2.bi2stamp = bi.bistamp)
INNER JOIN bo2(NOLOCK) ON (bo2.bo2stamp = bo.bostamp)
INNER JOIN bo3(NOLOCK) ON (bo3.bo3stamp = bo.bostamp)
INNER JOIN ag(NOLOCK) ON (ag.nome = bo3.u_nome)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cliente
        ,sum(valor) AS total2019
    FROM u_vendas2019
    WHERE month(data) <= month(getdate())
    GROUP BY cliente
    ) AS v ON (v.cliente = bo3.u_nome)
WHERE bo.ndos = 1
    AND year(bo.dataopen) = '2020'
    AND bo3.u_nome = 'Caroll'
    AND bo2.anulado = 0
GROUP BY ag.vendnm
    ,bo3.u_nome
    ,v.total2019
    ,bi.ETTDEB
```

I tried to use left join but it didn't work. Don't know how to do this.

Comment: Whats the logic behind it? Why should the total only be available on the first row?

Comment: This is part of a large query that return the data for an automatic email. So i just wanna the first row, so i can use sum in the last query and then have results with the group by rollup.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you must, AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: What is the current Sintax? I'm using this because it's an advice from the ERP company so there aren't any problems with the databse.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select a.NAME,
           a.QUANTITY,
           a.TEST,
           b.TOTAL
      from TABLE_A a 
 left join TABLE_B b on a.NAME = b.NAME
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The column total will be filled with the value 87 for every row. And i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: from what i have understood, you want the 4th column only in the first of every different name

```
select  table1.name,table1.quantity,table1.test,
    case when k.row = 1 then table2.total
         else null
    end
    from table1 inner join
    (
    select
        name,row_number() over(order by name asc) row
    from table1
    ) k on table1.name = k.name
    inner join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```